# Impala SQL: Count number of rows fetched

Tags: impala

`SHOW TABLE LIKE 'my_table';`

This will either return a matching table or empty result. (fetched 1 or 0 row)

How do I issue a `count` query to get "0" or "1" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with a SQL query today. You'll need support for querying Impala schema metadata as a table, see [IMPALA-1761](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-1761).